# jQuery append() - duplicate appends

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

In a scenario where I am appending something like a div to the html body I have noticed that jQuery is smart enough to prevent appending the object twice.

So for example take the following code:

```
$("body").append("<div id=\"divDialog\" title=\"Custom Dialog\">My dialog question?</div>");
$("#divDialog").dialog();
```

*No matter how many times I call the above method divDialog will only be created once (from what I can see).*

**In cases where you are not running in a tight loop is there anything wrong with allowing the append method to be called multiple times? Can this cause any problems?**

I am assuming in a loop it would be something to avoid...

Comment: I think it must be `$.fn.dialog()` which is doing something special; try just running the `$("body").append("<div id=\"divDialog\" title=\"Custom Dialog\">My dialog question?</div>");` a few times and you'll find it is created every time (the `#divDialog` selector will only find the first one).

Comment: BTW - You don't have to escape your double-quotes if you enclose everything in single quotes and that works vice-versa.

Comment: @Erik Reppen: Thanks I know. I prefer escaping.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: My testing doesnt agree with you. When specifying an ID jQuery seems to refuse to create multiple instances. If I only specify a class it does create multiple divs. (I have tried both using a selector and looking at the raw HTML) Could someone please confirm this? The first answer seems to suggest I am correct...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .append() duplicates content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249518/jquery-append-duplicates-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing wrong at all with running it next to each other. I don't have stats to back me, but from experience I can tell you that there's very little impact on performance. The exception would be if you're using it over and over again like in a loop, but you said that's not the case.

If both are equally easy, the better method would be to concatenate all of the HTML to append and do it at once.