# jQuery .append(), prepend(), after() ... duplicate elements and contents?

Tags: jquery, duplicates, append

In my code this command is run only once:

```
jQuery("#commentrating").append('A');
```

but inside the div `#commentrating` there appears two "A" elements! What may be causing this bug?

P.S. `.after()` is buggy as well :S

Comment: Please try to recreate your problem with http://jsfiddle.net/ and post the context of the code or provide a link to your site. We cannot help you much given only this line of code. It seems that for some reason this line is run twice.

Comment: There isn't enough information here, however it sounds like whatever event is causing the append is being triggered twice. That usually suggests a logic problem, such as binding a click event inside of a click event without unbinding it. does clicking it a third time cause AAA or AAAA to be added?

Comment: I agree with Tentonaxe.  I would add a console.log() after the append statement and then verify that it's only being called once.

Comment: A guess. .append is for appending a DOM object or html string, not strings of text. (use .text for that) Maybe jQuery is trying to close the 'A' tag?

Comment: Event is fired just after "jQuery(document).ready(function() {" so there is no other trigger or function interferring...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's caused by event-bubbling.(just a guess as long as no further info is available)

Assuming this:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    $('div')
      .click(function(e)
             {
              $('span',this).append('A');
             }
            );
  }
);
</script>
<div><div><b>click here:</b><span></span></div></div>
```

if you click on the text, the click will trigger on the inner div and bubble up to the outer div, the function will be executed 2 times.

To avoid this use stopPropagation()

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    $('div')
      .click(function(e)
             {
              e.stopPropagation();
              $('span',this).append('A');
             }
            );
  }
);
</script>
<div><div><b>click here:</b><span></span></div></div>
```

Comment: Event is fired just after "jQuery(document).ready(function() {" so there is no other trigger or function interferring...

Comment: There has been bugs in ready(), which jquery-version do you use? Put an alert or similar inside the ready-callback to determine if ready is called twice.

Answer (score -1):

## **Two possible causes:**

(when using **`append`**, **`appendTo`**, **`prepend`**, **`prependTo`** ...):

---

1) If you attach 2 **source** elements to 1 **destination** element, if you use:

```
$("destination").append("source");
```

jQuery somewhere in your html finds 2 `source_div` elements and appends both of them.

2) If you attach 1 **source** element to 2 **destination**, like:

```
$("destination").append("source");
```

probably in your html you have 2 `destination` elements:

```
<div>
    <div class="destination"></div>
    ......
    <div class="destination"></div>
</div>
```