# jQuery append duplicates content

Tags: jquery, append

I am new to jquery. I need help moving content. I am using the append method.

I want to be able to move each of the.links element into each .submitted element within the .node element. Right now append is adding all three .links to each .selected element.  I have provided the code and a link to JSFiddle below.

Thanks for your help

[Click here to view code in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andesign/SGgM8/)

jQuery

```
​$('.links').appendTo('.submitted');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="node" class="clearfix">
        <h2>Node Title 1</h2>
        <div class="submitted">September 30</div>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sollicitudin egestas mi, ac luctus orci eleifend pharetra</div>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#">Node 1 Link 1</a> | 
            <a href="#">Node 1 Link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="node" class="clearfix">
        <h2>Node Title 2</h2>
        <div class="submitted">September 29</div>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sollicitudin egestas mi, ac luctus orci eleifend pharetra</div>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#">Node 2 Link 1</a> | 
            <a href="#">Node 2 Link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="node" class="clearfix">
        <h2>Node Title 3</h2>
        <div class="submitted">September 26</div>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sollicitudin egestas mi, ac luctus orci eleifend pharetra</div>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#">Node 3 Link 1</a> | 
            <a href="#">Node 3 Link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
#wrapper { width:600px; margin:0 auto; }
h2 { clear:both; }
.node { border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC; }
.submitted { float:left; width:200px; padding:10px; background-color:#CCCCCC; }
.content { float:left; width:360px; padding:10px; }
```

Comment: What event would move them? Also note that you can use multiple classes like this: `class="node clearfix"` (separated by a single space).

Comment: The elements are moved, but they are being added multiple times
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andesign/SGgM8/)

Comment: No, they are not. The only duplication is your content. Every links section defined says "Link 1". See this update: http://jsfiddle.net/SGgM8/3/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .append() duplicates content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249518/jquery-append-duplicates-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have this:

```
<div class="node" class="clearfix">
    <h2>Node Title 3</h2>
    <div class="submitted">September 26</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sollicitudin egestas mi, ac luctus orci eleifend pharetra</div>
    <div class="links">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a> | 
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you want it to end up like this:

```
<div class="node" class="clearfix">
    <h2>Node Title 3</h2>
    <div class="submitted">
        September 26
        <a href="#">Link 1</a> | 
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sollicitudin egestas mi, ac luctus orci eleifend pharetra</div>
    <div class="links">
    </div>
</div>
```

Moving children elements from div.links to div.submitted.

If thats correct then you can do something like this:

```
$(".node").each( function() {
     //Get the links
     var links = $(this).children(".links").html();
     //Remove the links from the .links div
     $(this).children(".links").html("");
     //Append the links to the .submitted div
     $(this).children(".submitted").append(links);
});
```

This will iterate through every .node element found in the DOM. Inside the .each block $(this) refers to the .node element.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Gracias! yes this was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

when you do this

`$('.links').appendTo('.submitted')`

you are selecting **all** elements with class `.links` and adding them to **all** elements with class `.submitted`

**EDIT**

now i understood what you want :)

this fixes it

```
$(".links").each(function(){
    $(this).appendTo( $(this).prevAll('.submitted') );
});
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/SGgM8/8/

[image: ss]

Comment: `this` in your code refers to window or document object not `.links` elements. Is there any difference between this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZUxgU/ and your _working_ fiddle?

Comment: I updated the jsFiddle example
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/andesign/SGgM8/)
I want to move each set of links into each submitted div for each node.

Comment: Sebastian Perez gave me the solution. Sorry if my description was not clear. Thanks for your time. Did not mean to downgrade your answer.

Comment: this answer is definitely more elegant than the accepted answer by the OP

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
$('.links').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.appendTo($this.siblings('.submitted'));
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PwJNe/

Note that your markup is invalid, change this:

```
<div class="node" class="clearfix">
```

to:

```
<div class="node clearfix">
```

Comment: I updated the jsFiddle example
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/andesign/SGgM8/)
I want to move each set of links into each submitted div for each node.

Comment: @Adrian Have you tried the code in this answer? It seems it does what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can create array duplicate using Jquery: **

let array = $('li a');
let copyOfArray = array.clone().slice();

Answer (score -1):

Three links `.links` are added to each three `.submitted` elements

To add only one, restrict with `.first()` or some jquery filter

Example forked from your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LMbzY/

Comment: Downvote is because my answer is not appending each `.links` in its parent `.submitted`, but instead, takes the first links and put them in each `.submitted`. (answer too fast :)) (would be more elegant if the voter posted that comment, though...)