# Jquery .append() duplicate elements inside an <ul> tag

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm creating a forum and i want the comments to appear with their dates, this is the html:

```
<div id="forum" class="panel panel-default">
    <ul class="list-group">

    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm appending the elements with jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '../public/comment',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {

            $('#forum ul').empty();
            for (var i in response['comments'])
            {
                $('#forum ul').append('<li class="list-group-item"> <ul> <li class="list-group-item">' +
                    response['comments'][i].date + '</li> <li class="list-group-item">' +
                    response['comments'][i].comment + '</li> </ul> </li> '); 
            }
        }
    });
```

But for every comment that i append to the forum the rest of the comments are duplicated and attached to it. If i have three comments it shows 7, if i have 4 it shows 15.

I realize that deleting the ul tags from the jquery solves the problem, but i need these tags for aesthetic reasons. what can be wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .append() duplicates content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249518/jquery-append-duplicates-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing

```
$('#forum ul').append(...)
```

you append everything to every <ul> element within your #forum <div>, including the <ul> tags within your <li> tags.

Change it to

```
$('#forum>ul').append(...)
```

to select the immediate children only.

[See this post also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459821/css-selector-what-is-it)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that every ajax call gets ALL comments for that matter. In that case simply replace the entire html of your list each time.

```js
//clear your ul
$('#forum ul').html('');
//repopulate
$.ajax({
  url: '../public/comment',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {

    $('#forum ul').empty();
    for (var i in response['comments']) {
      $('#forum ul').append('<li class="list-group-item"> <ul> <li class="list-group-item">' +
        response['comments'][i].date + '</li> <li class="list-group-item">' +
        response['comments'][i].comment + '</li> </ul> </li> ');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm logging the result of the ajax call and everything is fine. anyway i was doing    $('#forum ul').empty(); inside the success function. apparently is something with the ul tag